# Create translation web services in java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, machine-translation

1. Create XML base with words?
2. When a client requires a particular word in the translation, the
   service checks for the word in its XML-based If there is a word,
   service as an output to the client broadcast a translated word. If
   the word does not exist in the XML file, the service broadcasts
   adequate message. Because testing in an XML file you need to add a
   few words.
3. Client benefits described service by calling the method translate,
   three string parameters. Example: `translate(”butterfly”, ”english”,
   ”russian”);`

SAXParser:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    sp.parse ("words.xml", new MySaxHandler());
}
}
```

Handler:

```
class MySaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private String actualNodeName;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    this.actualNodeName = qName;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if(!actualNodeName.equals("bs"))
        return;
    String nodeValue = new String(ch,start,length);

    if (!nodeValue.trim().equals(""))
        System.out.println (nodeValue);
}
}
```

Comment: What next  I am ..... ??

Comment: can you post the sample xml structure..?

Answer (score 0):

```
package servis;


Document doc;

public Prevodilac() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    String xmlFile ;

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile));
    doc = builder.parse(is);

}

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "pretraga")
public String pretraga(String key) {
    Element r = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList language = r.getElementsByTagName("phrase");
    String result = "Not Found";
    for(int index = 0;index<language.getLength();index++){
        Node attr = language.item(index).getAttributes().getNamedItem("key");
        if(attr)
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: need help from if(attr)..i need to check if the attribute corresponds to key parameter and fill result with attribute value